# When an HTML5 video is in FULLSCREEN mode in Chrome, can't place a custom div in front of the video

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html5-video

When an HTML5 video is in FULLSCREEN mode in Chrome, I can't place a custom div in front of the video. I have some javascript in a Chrome extension such that when user presses ALT+L, it shows a small div with some video info for 1.5 seconds. This works great when **not** in fullscreen mode. But when in fullscreen mode, the div doesn't show. I verified that keystrokes **are** being routed to my handler, but the code to show my custom div is apparently ignored when in fullscreen mode.

I just need some way to communicate this little bit of video info to the user when in fullscreen mode and ALT+L is pressed. Is there any way to do this in Chrome?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: You can use <track> element

Comment: For normal level web js code, since you can't listen for click on controls bar, and that you need an user gesture to call `requestFullscreen`, you'll have to use custom controls. Once done, you'll be able to call `requestFullscreen` on a wrapper containing both your video, and the notification element. Without it, you're stuck. Now, since you are writing a chrome extension, you may have less restrictions on how to call `requestFullscreen`, and you could be able to do the routing anyway, but this is unknown to me.. Here is some [non-working code](https://jsfiddle.net/63LycphL/) of what I mean.

Comment: Makyen: manifest.json is irrelevant to this question and I believe my origional post contains all relevant info.

Comment: Hey guest271314, you solved my problem. The `<track>` element was absolutely perfect. If you want to put that as the solution I'll accept it and give a point. I never knew about that element before. Thanks.